# How to create an API for JSP and EJB3 website

Tags: java, ios, web-services

I have an existing EJB3/Hibernate (backend) and JSP (frontend) website. I want build an api for the business logic so that it can be accessed to an iPhone app or Android app or even a mobile site.
I am reading about two such technologies in java i.e. RESTful webservices and JAX-WS (XML based webservice). Which one will be more feasible or are there any other technologies to use.

Please help me out as I am new to the webservices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend RESTful services using JAX-RS. They are quick to implement and easier (imo) to consume in mobile devices.

Here are some useful reading material:

- [JEE6 REST reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html)
- [Apache CXF REST reference](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html)
- [RESTEasy reference guide](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html)

Of course, you can also stand up both RESTful and WS endpoints for your services. The mapping is not one for one, but toolkits like CXF make it (somewhat) painless.

Comment: I don't get it. What is the difference between JAX-RS and RESTEasy?

Comment: JAX-RS is a ***specification*** (like JDBC, JTA, JEE), RESTEasy is an ***implementation*** that provides functionality matching the specification.

Answer (score 0):

The RESTful service would be a better choice,you can use Jersey ,if you are using Netbeans as IDE ,you can develop restful api conveniently

Answer (score 0):

An essential detail is whether you are the only one who will be developing the applications, or if you want a public API.

If you are the only one, I recommend SOAP/XML. This can be done using integrated server-side containers and simple annotations.

However, if you want to open up your API, I propose you use REST. **RESTEasy** is a very good framework for this, as is **JAX-RS**.